# How to write a formula to get a percentage using countIF and NOW() formula in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

How to create a calculated field in Quicksight to find a percentage of total number of 'Failed' models for the past one month over the total number of current active models

```
countIf({id}, {status} = 'Failed') / countIf({id}, {date} = now())
```

As a result, I'm getting blank datasets. What am I doing wrong that is not letting me get the valid percentage?